# Rspec: Difference between allow and allow_any_instance_of

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a simple MySQL wrapper class which will run a query and return results.

```
class Rsql
  def initialize(db)
    @client = Mysql2::Client
    @db = db
  end

  def execute_query()
    client = @client.new(@db)
    client.query("select 1")
  end

end
```

I want to test some stuff involving the results of the query, but I don't want to actually connect to a database to get the results. I tried this test, but it doesn't work:

```
RSpec.describe Rsql do

  it "does it" do
    mock_database = double
    rsql = Rsql.new(mock_database)

    mock_mysql_client = double
    allow(mock_mysql_client).to receive(:query).and_return({"1" => 1})

    allow_any_instance_of(Mysql2::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_mysql_client)
    expect(rsql.execute_query).to eq({"1" => 1})
  end

end
```

Replacing `allow_any_instance_of()` with `allow()` works. I was under the impression that `allow_any_instance_of()` was some kind of a global "pretend this class behaves in this way across the entire program" whereas `allow()` is for specific instances of a class.

Can someone explain this behavior to me? I'm new to Rspec, so I apologize if this answer is blatantly obvious. I tried searching for the answer, but I couldn't come up with the right search string to find one. Maybe I don't know enough to know when I've found it.

Answer (score 8):

As of RSpec 3.3 , `any_instance` is deprecated and not recommended to use in your tests.

[From the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance):

> any_instance is the old way to stub or mock any instance of a class
>   but carries the baggage of a global monkey patch on all classes. Note
>   that we generally recommend against using this feature.

You should only need to use `allow(some_obj)` going forward and the documentation has some great examples (see [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/basics/allowing-messages)).

Such as:

```
RSpec.describe "receive_messages" do
  it "configures return values for the provided messages" do
    dbl = double("Some Collaborator")
    allow(dbl).to receive_messages(:foo => 2, :bar => 3)
    expect(dbl.foo).to eq(2)
    expect(dbl.bar).to eq(3)
  end
end
```

Edit, if you really want to use any_instance, do so like this:

```
(Mysql2::Client).allow_any_instance.to receive(:something)
```

Edit2, your exact stub doesn't work because you're not stubbing an instance, you're stubbing *before* the object is initialized.  In that case you would do `allow(Mysql2::Client).to receive(:new)`.

Comment: I understand that I should use allow() by virtue of the fact that allow_any_instance_of doesn't actually work. My question is more along the lines of "why does allow() work"? 

Every example I've seen of allow() involves declaring a mock object and then allowing that mock object to receive and return stuff. The way I'm using it involves allowing any call to the Mysql2::Client.new() method to return a mock object. I then allow that ,ock object's query() method to return stuff. Why can't I allow Mysql2::Client.query() to return the stuff I want without this extra step?

Comment: Updated with an example for you

Comment: I'm not tied to using allow_any_instance. If they say to not use it, I won't use it. I just want to know why it doesn't work the way I'm trying to use it.

In any case, I was able to get allow() to work and I think I have a good handle on how to mock objects and stub methods off of them (and actual non-mocked objects as well). Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @PaulSpringer - just re-read my answer here and added a second edit as to why your exact mock didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this Rsql class seems a service

class Rsql
def initialize(db)
@client = Mysql2::Client
@db = db
end

```
  def execute_query()
    client = @client.new(@db)
    client.query("select 1")
  end

end
```

lets create a test for it, now we should to test this function `execute_query` with `subject ()`

and to create clients in db we can use `let!` like this

```
let!(:client1) do
          FactoryBot.create(...
```

with this we should not use `double` or something

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RsqlTest do

 subject(:clients) do
    Rsql.execute_query()
 end

 context 'select' do
    let!(:client1) do
      FactoryBot.create(...
    end

    it 'should return records' do
      expect(clients).to include(client1)
    end
  end

end
```